# Computer hard crash when debug-stepping (kernel panic in coreaudiod)

Tags: xcode6, openal

Since installing Xcode 6.1, at times, while debugging and stepping through code statements (obj-c), my computer crashes with a kernel panic in coreaudiod.

Has anyone seen/resolved this somehow ? tia

running in MBP , 16Gb memory (plenty free), no iTunes or audio process running, but process being stepped runs a background music with OpenAL prior to the initial breakpoint.

Comment: I've had the same thing since I upgraded to Yosemite.

Comment: Yes, Yosemite seems to be the key here. I installed 10.10.1 yesterday, see what gives.

Comment: Did the same but was able to replicate this also with the 10.10.1

Comment: Still seeing this with 10.10.2

Comment: @mkeiser using AppCode instead of exCode, i dont have this anymore. film at 11